# How can I read a file from a path, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, filereader, fileapi

There are a lot of solutions that are based on the fetch api or the XMLHttpRequest, but they return CORS or same-origin-policy errors.

The File/Filereader API works out of the box , but only for files chosen by the user via a input file (because that is the only way to import them as a File obj)

Is there a way to do something simple and minimal like

```
const myfile = new File('relative/path/to/file') //just use a path
const fr = new FileReader();
fr.readAsText(myfile);
```

Thanks

Comment: The browser isn't allowed to read directly from local files, it has to go through the file dialogue. Otherwise, web sites could read your files without you knowing it.

Comment: `//just use a path` What is that path relative to? The user's home directory? The web application's home directory? You can't use the former because that opens up a whole can of security worms on the client side. You can't use the latter because that opens up a whole can of security worms on the server side.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for the info. So either by use input or files served by server

Answer (score -5):

Try the following JS, this will use fs to read the file and if it exists it will turn it into a string and output to console. You can change it up to however you'd like.

```js
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: The OP is using the File API in the browser, not NodeJS. If they were using NodeJS, we already have many answers for that question.